# Clicking on a tag in your profile searches for the user and the tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

For instance, if I want to see all the Javascript tags I clicked, here's the URL that appears in my profile:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:15+[javascript]
```

I think that the `user:15+` is wrong (or something is off) because the search on the right side says:

> posts containing
>   user:15
>   within these tags
>   javascript

Answer (score 4):

Seems right to me. `user:15+[javascript]` decoded would be `user:15 [javascript]` (the `+` becomes a space).  So, it is doing a search for posts by `user:15` (you) that have a tag of javascript.

EDIT:  Checked StackOverflow and it does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, this is by design. It's been this way for probably close to a year.